# Can I combine these integrals?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, proof-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a question where I am given that

$$\langle|x|^n\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|^nP(x)\,dx$$

And must show that $\langle|x|\rangle^2\leq \langle|x|^2\rangle$ using Schwarz's inequality.

**EDIT:** $P(x)\,dx$ is probability of finding a particle between $x$ and $x+dx$ so these are probabilities and positive!

I have come to the expression of

$$\langle |x|^n\rangle \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty P^2(x)\,dx$$

Now I feel like my lack of familiarity with integral manipulation is limiting me. I think Scwarz's inequality woyld imply that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty P^2(x) \, dx = \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x) \, dx\right)^2$$

So then perhaps I could say that

$$\langle|x|^n\rangle \leq \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x) \, dx \right) \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x) \, dx$$

Then if I could combine $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x) \, dx$

to

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^2P(x) \, dx$$

then the problem is complete! I am just not sure if this is allowed and would appreciate any extra information on combining/manipulating integrals!

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle a \rangle,$ not $<a>.$ I edited accordingly and cleaned up some other things as well. $\qquad$

Comment: You wrote "using Schwarz's inequality", but then you neglected that in the rest of what you wrote. To apply Schwarz's inequality, you need an inner product. What is the inner product here? $\qquad$